# What is that "Dream Card" you get from Ysera?

Tags: hearthstone

Ysera is a legendary monster with 9 mana cost 4 attack and 12 HP that has an effect which states: "At the end of your turn, draw a dream card".

What exactly is that "dream card"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Ysera](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Ysera)'s dream ability actually consists of 5 possible cards.  You will randomly obtain one of the following at the end of your turn:

- [Dream](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=808/dream): 0 mana - return a minion to the owner's hand
- [Emerald Drake](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=489/emerald-drake): 4 mana - 7/6 minion
- [Laughing Sister](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=340/laughing-sister): 3 mana - 3/5 cannot be the target of spells or hero powers
- [Nightmare](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=217/nightmare): 0 mana - give a minion +5/+5, destroy it at the start of your next turn
- [Ysera Awakens](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=301/ysera-awakens): 2 mana - deal 5 damage to all characters other than Ysera

All of these cards are very powerful.  And also considering Ysera herself has 12 health, you will most likely obtain multiple dream cards in a game, making her one of the best Legendaries in the game.

Comment: Damn, those dream cards seem OP. I've had my enemy use Ysera that's why I asked the question. I quickly silenced his Ysera though so I didn't see what he can get from it xD

Comment: @chrishatez well at the minimum they would get 1 card, but yea, silence is a good way of shutting it down.

Comment: Mind control! ;D Actually, as the description says, MC is the card most likely to make people punch a wall for this exact reason. NO IT'S NOT OP DAMMIT! ;P